# Azure Form Recognizer Not Behaving As Expected

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

I am having an issue with FormRecognizer not behaving how I have seen it should. Here is the dilemma

I have an Invoice that, when run through https://{endpoint}/formrecognizer/v2.0/layout/analyze
it recognized the table in the Invoice and generates the proper JSON with the  "tables" node. Here is an example of part of it

```
 {
                    "rows": 8,
                    "columns": 8,
                    "cells": [
                        {
                            "rowIndex": 0,
                            "columnIndex": 4,
                            "columnSpan": 3,
                            "text": "% 123 F STREET Deer Park TX 71536",
                            "boundingBox": [
                                3.11,
                                2.0733
                            ],
                            "elements": [
                                "#/readResults/0/lines/20/words/0",
                                "#/readResults/0/lines/20/words/1"

                            ]
                        }
```

When I train a model with NO labels file https://{endpoint}/formrecognizer/v2.0/custom/models It does not generate an empty "tables" node, but it generates (tokens). Here is an example of the one above without "table"

```
{
                    "key": {
                        "text": "__Tokens__12",
                        "boundingBox": null,
                        "elements": null
                    },
                    "value": {
                        "text": "123 F STREET",
                        "boundingBox": [
                            5.3778,
                            2.0625,
                            6.8056,
                            2.0625,
                            6.8056,
                            2.2014,
                            5.3778,
                            2.2014
                        ],
                        "elements": null
                    },
                    "confidence": 1.0
                }
```

I am not sure exactly where this is not behaving how intended, but any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you train a model WITH labeling files,  then call FR Analyze(),  the FR service will call the Layout service, which returns tables in "pageResults" section.